# Footer empty, static blocks not showing up

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, newsletter, footer

Good morning,
it seems my footer content has disappeared and I don't know where to.
I want to put the newsletter module in there, but it completely vanished.
here's the code that I added temporarily which is supposed to make it show up.
It's not working. (I found that code off of Google, but most results seem to be 2009 or 2010)

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

for the static block and

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="newsletter"}}
```

for the CMS page.
I've checked if the phtml and xml files have their necessary bits of code in them; subscribe.phtml is still "out-of-the-box", and once again, it is there

```
    <default>
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" as="newsletter" before="-" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Can you help me figure out how to show the newsletter module (or static blocks in general) in the footer as it is supposed to be, please?
Much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: is only newsletter model  vanished?

Comment: no, like I said the whole footer is empty
[link](http://www.wein-partner.at/shop/index.php)

Comment: remove all newletter code  from xml  and check that footer is coming or not

Comment: removed from "page.xml", no changes; I can hardly remove it from "newsletter.xml", now can I?

Comment: since adding a backend-login won't really help, here's the .xml-files: [xml-files](http://codepaste.net/29ic88)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call newsletter at footer by using php code

```
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("newsletter/subscribe")
->setTemplate("newsletter/subscribe.phtml")->toHtml();
```

Comment: I suppose I have to add that in the template file?

Comment: aside from the typo "`" at the end of newsletter, it hasn't changed the site.

Comment: since no further information came, I fixed the problem myself with this code snippet.